# initializer_list and template type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, initializer-list

Consider the function:

```
template<typename T>
void printme(T&& t) {
  for (auto i : t)
    std::cout << i;
}
```

or any other function that expects one parameter with a begin()/end() - enabled type.

**Why is the following illegal?**

`printme({'a', 'b', 'c'});`

When all these are legitimate:

```
printme(std::vector<char>({'a', 'b', 'c'}));
printme(std::string("abc"));
printme(std::array<char, 3> {'a', 'b', 'c'});
```

We can even write this:

```
const auto il = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
printme(il);
```

or

```
printme<std::initializer_list<char>>({'a', 'b', 'c'});
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Your first line `printme({'a', 'b', 'c'})` is illegal because the template argument `T` could not be inferred. If you explicitly specify the template argument it will work, e.g. `printme<vector<char>>({'a', 'b', 'c'})` or `printme<initializer_list<char>>({'a', 'b', 'c'})`.

The other ones you listed are legal because the argument has a well-defined type, so the template argument `T` can be deduced just fine.

Your snippet with `auto` also works because `il` is considered to be of type `std::initializer_list<char>`, and therefore the template argument to `printme()` can be deduced.

---

The only "funny" part here is that `auto` will pick the type `std::initializer_list<char>` but the template argument will not. This is because § 14.8.2.5/5 of the C++11 standard explicitly states that this is a non-deduced context for a template argument:

> A function parameter for which the associated argument is an initializer list (8.5.4) but the parameter does not have std::initializer_list or reference to possibly cv-qualified std::initializer_list type. *[Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class T> void g(T);
> g({1,2,3}); // error: no argument deduced for T
> ```
>
> *— end example ]*

However with `auto`, § 7.1.6.4/6 has explicit support for `std::initializer_list<>`

> if the initializer is a *braced-init-list* (8.5.4), with `std::initializer_list<U>`.

Comment: +1 I learned something. that elevates `std::initialiser_list<>` to something beyond an ordinary library function.

Comment: Just for completeness. Here is a way to  solve the problem: http://pastebin.com/huEGwnDt

Comment: Do we know *why* this is the case? It seems pretty strange to me that if I want to allow a template function (maybe a range-based algorithm) to take a initializer list argument, I have to provide an overload for `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: @JosephMansfield I haven't managed to find a definitive answer but I suspect it's to do with braces being used for uniform initialization. The call `g({1, 2, 3})` could also be taken to mean `g(Foo(1, 2, 3))` where `Foo` is any class with a constructor taking three ints.

Comment: @4ZM If you call without parameters, the call is ambiguous.

Answer (score 13):

You can also overload the function to explicitly take an argument of type initializer_list.

```
template<typename T>
void printme(std::initializer_list<T> t) {
  for (auto i : t)
    std::cout << i;
}
```

Comment: Sure, but that would make the other versions fail, e.g. `printme(std::vector<char>({'a', 'b', 'c'}));`. Template specialization won't work here unfortunately.

Comment: Oh, but that's great! Thank you. I thought I had tried this, but I was wrong. Template specialization works fine here. Since the function can be implemented in _exactly_ the same way, all that remains is how to figure out how to make one of them call the other...

Comment: Works fine. You can even improve on that solution by implementing perfect forwarding for the initializer_list like this:  http://pastebin.com/1ttGniBH ?

Answer (score 5):

This is specifically covered under § 14.8.2.5/5

> A function parameter for which the associated argument is an
> initializer list but the parameter does not have
> `std::initializer_list` or reference to possibly cv-qualified
> `std::initializer_list` type. [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<class T> void g(T);
> g({1,2,3}); // error: no argument deduced for T
> ```
>
> —end example ]

To make it work, you can specify the template argument type explicitly.

```
printme<std::initializer_list<int>>( {1,2,3,4} );
```