# Why variadic function can't "eat" the list-initialization argument in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-functions, compiler-bug, list-initialization

The sample code is:

```
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<int, int>> map;

    map.emplace(1, {1, 1});

    return 0;
}
```

Where the `emplace()` has signature, like:

```
template <class... _Args>
pair<iterator, bool> emplace(_Args&&... __args);
```

The `gcc` says that function expectes 0 arguments - 2 provided. The `clang` says that function expects 1 argument - 2 provided.

I don't even understand - what the problem is with this code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that `{1, 1}` is not an expression and has no type. Since it has no type, it cannot be deduced into the template argument list. Neither of them are correct, because the issue has nothing to do with the number of arguments provided.

Comment: @Jefffrey: No, `{...}` is _not_ an expression. The first is a special-casing for `auto`-deduction which should really never have been there (and will hopefully be removed sometime in the future), and the second one is just construction from braced-init-list.

Comment: @Massa: Yes, that would be sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

> I don't even understand - what the problem is with this code?

For some obscure reason, an initializer-list argument is a non-deduced context, see [initializer_list and template type deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12431495/341970). This is because § 14.8.2.5/5 of the C++11 standard says so. I don't know the rationale for this seemingly inconsistent and counterintuitive behavior either but we are not alone:

- [1564. Template argument deduction from an initializer list](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1564)
- [C++ Type Deduction and Why You Care](http://vimeo.com/97344493) by Scott Meyers, starting from 37:00
- [If braced initializers have no type, why is the committee so insistent on deducing one for them?](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.co.at/2014/03/if-braced-initializers-have-no-type-why.html)

As for your situation, perhaps the easiest fix is:

```
map.emplace(1, std::make_pair(1, 1));
```

Comment: The reason is not obscure - tell me, what kind of `initializer_list` should `{1, "hi"}` be?

Comment: @Xeo I don't get your example. `auto x = { 1, "hi" };` is also a compile time error, so what is the point you are trying to make?

Comment: @Xeo I guess the reason, if any, must be something else. My guess is that allowing this kind of deduction on function template arguments, could backfire. Although, I failed to come up with an example.

Comment: The problem is that `auto x = {1, 1};` is allowed at all. It's a special case in the standard, and it's an unnecessary hack that should be removed. :/

Comment: @Xeo I guess it is too late to change that, that would be break a lot of code. But do you see any corner case in which deducing `initializer_list` for a function template argument could backfire?