# Why I can not return initializer list from lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14, initializer-list

Why this code is not valid?

```
auto foo = [] () {
    return {1, 2};     
};
```

However, this is valid since the `initializer_list` is used just to initialize a `vector` not to return itself:

```
auto foo = [] () -> std::vector<int> {
    return {1, 2};     
};
```

Why I can not return `initializer_list`? It could be useful. For example, a lambda that can be used to initialize a `vector` or a `list` or ... with some default values for something.

Comment: `std::initializer_list` has reference semantics, therefore the thing you return would immediately dangle.

Comment: @T.C Thanks. I did not understand. but I think there is enough keywords to search for.

Comment: @T.C. Really? I thought it copy-initialized each element as if it was an array. Do you have a link I can look at or standards quote?

Comment: @TartanLlama http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#6

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Lambda return type deduction uses the `auto` rules, which normally would have deduced `std::initializer_list` just fine. However, the language designers banned deduction from a braced initializer list in a return statement ([dcl.spec.auto]/7):

> If the deduction is for a `return` statement and the initializer is a
>   *braced-init-list* ([dcl.init.list]), the program is ill-formed.

The reason for this is that `std::initializer_list` has reference semantics ([[dcl.init.list]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#6)). 
 `[]() -> std::initializer_list<int> { return {1, 2}; }` is every bit as bad as 
`[]() -> const int & { return 1; }`. The lifetime of the backing array of the `initializer_list` object ends when the lambda returns, and you are left with a dangling pointer (or two).

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4833dabea31f75ca):

```
#include <vector>

struct Noisy {
    Noisy()  { __builtin_printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
    Noisy(const Noisy&) { __builtin_printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
    ~Noisy() { __builtin_printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
};

int main()
{
    auto foo = []() -> std::initializer_list<Noisy> { return {Noisy{}, Noisy{}}; };
    std::vector<Noisy> bar{foo()};
}
```

Output:

```
Noisy::Noisy()
Noisy::Noisy()
Noisy::~Noisy()
Noisy::~Noisy()
Noisy::Noisy(const Noisy&)
Noisy::Noisy(const Noisy&)
Noisy::~Noisy()
Noisy::~Noisy()
```

Note how the copy constructors are called after all the `Noisy` objects created so far have been destroyed already.

Comment: So it is simply not valid to do this at all.. Thanks sir for explanation.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Your `vector` version works fine, but is not ideal. I'd consider returning an `std::array` which seems to be close to what you want, except you have to manually count the number of objects. Maybe you can get something done with `constexpr` to automatically extract the array size.

Answer (score 7):

`std::initializer_list` can't be deduced by a template argument, which means you'll have to tell the lambda what it is explicitly:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    auto foo = []() -> std::initializer_list<int> { return {1, 2}; };
    std::vector<int> bar{foo()};
    for (int x : bar) { std::cout << x << "  "; };
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a57d386394368219).  Here's the rationale behind this from the [initializer list proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2100.pdf):

> Can an initializer list be used as a template argument? Consider:
>
> ```
> template<class T> void f(const T&);
> f({ }); // error
> f({1});
> f({1,2,3,4,5,6});
> f({1,2.0}); // error
> f(X{1,2.0}); // ok: T is X
> ```
>
> There is obviously no problem with the last call (provided **X{1,2.0}** itself is valid)
>   because the template argument is an **X**. Since we are not introducing arbitrary lists of
>   types (product types), we cannot deduce **T** to be **{int,double}** for **f({1,2.0})**, so that call is
>   an error. Plain {} does not have a type, so **f({})** is also an error.
>
> This leaves the homogeneous lists. Should **f({1})** and **f({1,2,3,4,5,6})** be accepted? If so,
>   with what meaning? If so, the answer must be that the deduced type, **T**, is
>   **initializer_list**. Unless someone comes up with at least one good use of this simple
>   feature (a homogeneous list of elements of type **E** is deduced to be an
>   **initializer_list**), we won’t propose it and all the examples will be  errors: No template
>   argument can be deduced from an (unqualified) initializer list. One reason to be cautious
>   here is that we can imagine someone getting confused about the possible interpretations
>   of single-element lists. For example, could **f({1})** invoke **f<int>(1)**? No, that would be
>   quite inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks. But so strange.. it's just a problem of auto deduced! Are you sure that it is totaly valid and no UB or any other problem could be happen here? becuase i have doubt that it is valid but just a deduction problem..

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Yes, the standard explicitly says `std::initializer_list` can't be type-deduced.  Here's an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431495/initializer-list-and-template-type-deduction) that goes into more details.

Comment: Do not confuse `std::initializer_list` with a braced init list

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Found the rationale from the proposal, should make things clearer for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can return an `initializer_list` from the function either like that:

```
return std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2};
```

or

```
auto ret = {1, 2};
return ret;
```

The reason is, that the `auto` variable declaration uses different rules than the `auto` return type deduction. The first one has a special rule for this case, and the second one uses plain template type deduction.

This is discussed at length in Scott Meyers Effective Modern C++, Item 2. There is also a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQxj20X-tIU) and [slides](http://www.aristeia.com/TalkNotes/C++TypeDeductionandWhyYouCareCppCon2014.pdf) from him about the topic.