# Return initializer list instead of vector in std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, initializer-list, std-function

> **Edit:** It is not duplicated of the linked question (which is mine also). Here all the return types are `std::vector`. I do not want to
>   return an `initializer-list`. I want to fill the returned
>   `std::vector` by `initializer-list` directly

Let us take those four cases:

1)

```
//Acceptable
std::vector<int> foo(){
    return std::vector<int>{1}; 
}
```

2)

```
//Acceptable
std::vector<int> foo(){
    return {1};    
}
```

3)

```
//Acceptable
std::function<std::vector<int>()> foo=[](){
    return std::vector<int>{1}; 
};
```

4)

```
//NOT Acceptable
std::function<std::vector<int>()> foo=[](){
    return {1}; 
};
```

Why 4 is not acceptable since 2 is acceptable? what is the different between them? Moreover, the most strange thing that this is acceptable:

```
//Acceptable
auto  bar=[]()->std::vector<int>{
    return {1}; 
};
```

What is wrong with `std::function` and `initializer-list`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I can not return initializer list from lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361408/why-i-can-not-return-initializer-list-from-lambda)

Comment: Before I Mjölnir this: How does the linked answer not answer this in your eyes?

Comment: It is different. That question about returning an Initializer-list. here the return type in all cases is a vector.

Comment: The return type doesn't matter. The point is that you cannot deduce the type automatically, so you need to manually specify it.

Comment: @nwp Doesn't this consider as a manually specify? "std::function<std::vector<int>()>"

Comment: `auto  bar=[]()->std::vector<int>{` counts because you explicitly say what the lambda has to return. `std::function<std::vector<int>()> foo=[](){` does not count, because you first deduce the return type of the lambda, then assign it. C++ doesn't take into account what you may assign the lambda to when deciding on a type, it sees `return {1}`, which is an `std::initializer_list<int>` (I think).

Comment: Ah! I got it now.. Please you may make this as an answer.. thanks

Comment: I think now you can let @BaummitAugen close it as a dupe.

Comment: @nwp But actually this question extend the concept. and the answer there does not contain your note.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`auto bar=[]()->std::vector<int>{` specifies the return type of the lambda `bar` to be `std::vector<int>`.

`std::function<std::vector<int>()> foo=[](){` does not specify the return type of `foo`, because you first deduce the return type of the lambda, then assign it.

C++ does not take into account what you may assign the lambda to when deciding on a type, it sees return {1}, which is an `std::initializer_list<int>`, which is incompatible with a `std::function<std::vector<int>>`.

Answer (score 1):

This variation compiles:

```
std::function<std::vector<int>()> foo=[]()->std::vector<int>{
    return {1}; 
};
```

This is identical to your case 4, except for the explicit return type in the lambda expression. This shows that the type of the `std::function<>` declaration does not propagate into the parsing of the lambda expression; the lambda is parsed independently of the surrounding expression.

*I'm not sure whether this is a feature of the C++ language standard or of the limitations of real-world compilers (I tested with `g++ -std=c++11`), since I'm not too much of a language lawyer.*

Answer (score 1):

The return type of the lambda in (4) is `auto`, and not `std::vector` as in (2) and as in your last sample, where you are still using a lambda, but forced the return type.

The deduction of `auto` in `return {1}` leads to `std::initializer_list<int>()`, that's different from `std::vector<int>()` the `std::function` expects.

Comment: *"The deduction of auto in return {1} leads to std::initializer_list<int>()"*. The fact that `a` in `auto a={1};` becomes an initializer list does not imply that `[]{return {1};}` deduces `initializer_list` as a return type.