# Pack expansion of variadic list of types into initializer list of complex types - is it legal?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17, stdinitializerlist

I would like to "materialize" a variadic types list into an initializer_list of related values.
For example, having an `std::tuple` of several `std::integral_constant<T, x>` get an `std::initializer_list<T>{...}`.
In general case, I would like to get initializer_list of some complex type, like `std::string`.

But the following simple example gives me a crash when compiled by Clang (although it works with GCC, at least on Coliru), so I suspect UB (or bug in Clang):

```
template <class... Ts>
std::initializer_list<const std::string> materialize()
{
    return {
      std::to_string(Ts::value)...
    };
}

void print_out()
{
   for (const auto & x : materialize<std::true_type, std::false_type>()) {
      std::cout << x << "\n";
   }
}
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b475ebef3b8c124)

So, is such code legal? In C++11/14/17?

Comment: Does it compile?

Comment: [This answer](https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/35361729/9593596) is for a different context, but covers returning `std::initializer_list` instances, too.

Comment: Damn, I totally forgot about transient nature of initializer_lists... Thanks @rafix07 and @songyuanyao!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two things about initializer_list:

> Initializer lists may be implemented as a **pair of pointers** or pointer
>   and length. Copying a std::initializer_list **does not copy the**
>   **underlying objects**.

and

> The underlying array is not guaranteed to exist after the lifetime of
>   the original initializer list object has ended. The storage for
>   std::initializer_list is unspecified (i.e. it could be automatic,
>   temporary, or static read-only memory, depending on the situation).

so in this line

```
return {
      std::to_string(Ts::value)...
    };
```

you are creating local array, initializer_list keeps pointer to the beginning / end of this array, when function goes out of scope you have dangling pointers.

Comment: But should this be the case in C++17 also with [prvalue materialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization)? IOW does the conversion from the *braced-init-list* to the `initializer_list` happen in the `return` statement (and then a copy of the object is returned), or should the return value be *directly* initialized from the *braced-init-list*? In the latter case, it seems like the lifetime of the values should be extended along with that of the (original) `initializer_list`. Where is the flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: @ArneVogel Because the `initializer_list` is the return value of a function, the lifetime of the temporary array is not extended, just like returning a reference to a local variable.

Comment: @xskxzr Thanks, I think I get it now. Relevant std. quote: "The array has the same lifetime as any other temporary object, except that initializing an `initializer_­list` object from the array extends the lifetime of the array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary."[1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.list#6) – IOW, the `initializer_list` extends the lifetime of the temp. array, *but only* in contexts where a reference would also extend the lifetime of a temporary (i.e. when initializing a named variable at local, namespace or class-static scope, but not in a `return`).

Comment: @ArneVogel Right, and there is a mistake in my previous reply... I meant "just like returning a reference to a temporary object".

Answer (score 3):

The underlying array of [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) is a local temporary object in fact. When get out of `materialize` it has been destroyed. Copying an `std::initializer_list` doesn't copy the underlying array, the content of the returned `std::initializer_list` is always invalid and trying to access the content of the returned `std::initializer_list` leads to UB.

(emphasis mine)

> Initializer lists may be implemented as a pair of pointers or pointer
>   and length. **Copying a std::initializer_list does not copy the
>   underlying objects**.
>
> **The underlying array is a temporary array** of type `const T[N]`, in
>   which each element is copy-initialized (except that narrowing
>   conversions are invalid) from the corresponding element of the
>   original initializer list. The lifetime of the underlying array is the
>   same as any other temporary object, except that initializing an
>   initializer_list object from the array extends the lifetime of the
>   array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary (with the same
>   exceptions, such as for initializing a non-static class member). The
>   underlying array may be allocated in read-only memory.