# How to do the conditional variable initialization at compiler time?

Tags: c++, c++11

C++11 standard have `std::conditional<>` template for the type selection by the some boolean condition at compiler time. 
How to do the same operation but for select the init value for variable initialization? Similar to `type a = (exp) ? first_value : second_value;`.

I use my template:

```
template<bool B, typename T>
inline constexpr T&& conditional_initialize(T&& i1, T&& i2) {
    return B ? std::move(i1) : std::move(i2);
}
```

But it can be used only for POD types: `int a = conditional_initialize<true>(1, 2);`.
For array initialization this template is compiled with error. Wrong compile example: `int a[] = conditional_initialize<true>({1, 2}, {3,4,5});`

> Error message: ***[no matching function for call to 'conditional_initialize(<brace-enclosed initializer list>, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)';](http://cpp.sh/5f6rb)***

Who can help me with template?

Comment: @AndyG No, it's `std::initializer_list<int>`

Comment: `int a[] = conditional_initialize<true>({1, 2}, {3,4,5});` This cannot work, you cannot copy or move construct built-in arrays.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 it would be indeed, but unfortunately [templates cannot deduce `std::initializer_list`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12431810/3233393).

Comment: First, `int[]` is a POD type.  Second you cannot initialize an `int a[]` from an `initializer_list<int>`, which is pretty much the best thing you can hope `{1,2}` is deduced to be in that call. `{}` constructs are not expressions, so they cannot be stored perfectly in a typed variable or parameter.  They can be use to construct typed storage, but that typed storage is not the same thing as the `{}`.  This is one of the failings of "perfect" forwarding.

Comment: @Quentin They can, it just takes work, and that works isn't done, nor is it sufficient (add an overload that takes `(std::initializer_list<T> i1, std::initializer_list<T> i2)` for example).

Comment: Yakk, this sample not works too - http://cpp.sh/8aain

Comment: @23W because as he stated, you can't initialize a built-in array with an `std::initializer_list`. For one thing, the built-in array needs to know its length at compile time and the `std::initializer_list` hides that information until run time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
template<class T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M, bool b>
std::array<T, b?N:M>
conditional_array( std::array<T, N>&& lhs, std::array<T, M>&& rhs ) {
  return std::move(std::get<b?0:1>( std::tie(lhs, rhs) ) );
}
```

this gives you:

```
auto a = conditional_array<int,2,3,true>({{1, 2}}, {{3,4,5}});
```

which is close.

In general, `{}` constructs are not expressions, they cannot be perfectly forwarded through any mechanism through another variable.

We can also get:

```
auto a = cond_init<true>( make_array(1,2), make_array(3,4,5) );
```

with a bit more work.

```
template<bool Test, class A, class B>
std::conditional_t<Test,A,B>
cond_init(A a, B b) {
  return std::move( std::get<Test?0:1>( std::tie(a,b) ) );
}
template<class T0, class...Ts>
std::array< std::decay_t<T0>, sizeof...(Ts)+1 >
make_array( T0&& t0, Ts&&...ts ) {
  return {{std::forward<T0>(t0), std::forward<Ts>(ts)...}};
}
```

I didn't make these `constexpr`, because lazy.

Comment: @23W isn't that just my `cond_init` and manual `make_array` case with small changes?  I was lazy in that I did not audit of `std::tie` and the like are sufficiently `constexpr` for whatever version of C++ you used.

Comment: Yes it is. It is modification of your code for single approach for simple types and c++ std array (which are different types for different sizes).