# Constructing a mixin based on variadic templates by forwarding constructor parameters

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to construct a mixin template whose bases are all passed as variadic template parameters.  I would like to construct the mixin by passing the constructor parameters of each mixin class as a parameter to a variadic template constructor

The variadic template constructor when called with objects of each mixin class type compiles.  But if I pass the constructor parameter of each mixin class (all the classes have a single parameter constructor), it doesn't compile

I am using gcc 7.0 with -std=c++1z

What am I doing wrong?

```
 #include <vector>
 #include <string>
 #include <unordered_map>
 #include <iostream>

 template < typename... T >
 struct Mixin : T...
 {
     Mixin() = delete;
     Mixin(Mixin const &) = delete;
     Mixin(Mixin &&) = delete;

     template < typename... U >
     Mixin(U &&... v) : T(std::forward < U >(v))...
     {
     }
 };

 int main()
 {
     using A = std::vector < std::string >;
     using B = std::unordered_map < std::string, std::string >;
     using C = std::string;
     using M = Mixin < A, B, C >;

     //  This doesn't compile
     M m1{{"hello", "world"}, { {"hello",  "world" }, {"world",  "hello"} }, "hello"};

     //  This compiles
     A a({"hello", "world"}); B b({ {"hello",  "world" }, {"world",  "hello"} }); C c("hello");
     M m2{a, b, c};
 }
```

Comment: One major problem (unrelated to your question though) is that the standard containers (and `std::string`) aren't really designed to be inherited from. They don't have virtual destructors.

Comment: and the compiler error is ... ?

Comment: _"It doesn't compile"_ Go on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `std::initializer_list` cannot be deduced from a *forwarding-reference*. In fact, explicitly specifying `std::initializer_list` makes your code compile:

```
M m1{
    std::initializer_list<std::string>{"hello", "world"}, 
    std::initializer_list<std::pair<const std::string, std::string>>{{"hello",  "world" },{"world",  "hello"} }, 
    "hello"};
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/eqRqGmU3sRPuqux8)

You can find more information about `std::initializer_list` and deduction [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431495/initializer-list-and-template-type-deduction).

---

You can force deduction of `std::initializer_list` by creating an helper `make_il` function:

```
template <typename... Ts>
auto make_il(Ts&&... xs) 
{ 
    return std::initializer_list<std::common_type_t<Ts...>>{
        std::forward<Ts>(xs)...}; 
}
```

Your final code will look like:

```
using namespace std::literals::string_literals;          
using kvp = std::pair<const std::string, std::string>;

M m1{
    make_il("hello"s, "world"s), 
    make_il(kvp("hello"s,  "world"s), kvp("world"s,  "hello"s)), 
    "hello"};
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/EKjdtlIY2ZW912bl)