# How to invoke the constructor of a class in C++ template?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, constructor

Consider a C++ template class (mixin class) that inherits from the same class declared on the template, i.e.,

```
template <class Model>
class Mixin : public Model {
  ...
}
```

The motivation is to reuse this `Mixin` to extend methods for different `Model` classes. For example, for a model class `ModelOne`,

```
class ModelOne {
public: 
    ModelOne (int a, int b) { ... }
}
```

is 'dressed' up by the `Mixin` class and further extended as

```
class Realization : public Mixin<ModelOne> {
...
}
```

How do I explicitly invoke - in `Realization` class - the constructor of `ModelOne` class? Different model class may have different constructor signature.

Answer (score 1):

`Realization` derives from `Mixin<ModelOne>`, so it needs to invoke the constructor for `Mixin<ModelOne>`, not for `ModelOne` directly.  The constructor for `Mixin` can then invoke the constructor for its `Model`.  But if `Mixin` doesn't know which parameters the `Model` constructor takes, then `Mixin` will have to use variadic template parameters to pass through all specified argument values, eg:

```cpp
template<typename... T>
struct Mixin : T...
{
    Mixin() = delete;
    Mixin(Mixin const &) = delete;
    Mixin(Mixin &&) = delete;

    template<typename... U>
    Mixin(U&&... v) : T(std::forward<U>(v))... { }
};

class ModelOne
{
public:
    ModelOne (int a, int b) { ... }
};

class Realization : public Mixin<ModelOne>
{
...
public:
    Realization() : Mixin<ModelOne>(1, 2) {} 
}
```

Also see: [Constructing a mixin based on variadic templates by forwarding constructor parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676267/)

Comment: Interesting answer. I think "variadic template parameters" fulfills the need here.

Comment: However, the compiler kept complaining ``error: mismatched argument pack lengths while expanding ‘T’
     Mixin(U &&... v) : T(std::forward <U>(v))... {}``. This error appears in both g++-5 and g++-7 and it is perhaps not related to the compiler version.

Comment: @Xavier my variadic template kung-fu is no so good, so I'm sure it is just a matter of tweaking the syntax to make it work.