# Why can't I use initializer_list in with variadic template?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, initializer-list

I do not get why I cannot use `initializer_list` with variadic templates.

This code:

```
template <class... TArgs>
void Func(string name, TArgs&&... args)
{
}

Func(string("name1"), { "option1", "option2" });
```

gives me error:

```
too many arguments to function 'void Func(std::string, TArgs&& ...) [with TArgs = {}; std::string = std::basic_string<char>]'`
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431495/initializer-list-and-template-type-deduction) applies to your question too. Very Similar

Comment: @WhiZTiM thanks. It turned out it has nothing to do with variadic templates.