# std::make_unique's (and emplace, emplace_back's) awkward deduction for initializer_list arguments

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr, initializer-list, c++17

Say I have this struct:

```
struct position
{
  int x, y;
};
```

and another class that takes this as constructor argument:

```
class positioned
{
public:
  positioned(position p) : pos(p) {}
private:
  position pos;
};
```

How can I get the simple

```
auto bla = std::make_unique<positioned>({1,2});
```

to work?

Currently, the compiler tries to match through the `initializer_list<int>` and invoke the array variant of `make_unique`, which is silly, because `positioned` has only one constructor. The same issue arises for `emplace` and `emplace_back` functions. Pretty much any function that forwards its variadic template arguments to a class's constructor seems to exhibit this behaviour.

I understand I can resolve this by

1. giving `positioned` a two `int` argument constructor and dropping the `{}` in the call to `make_unique`, or
2. explicitly specifying the type of the argument to `make_unique` as `position{1,2}`.

Both seem overly verbose, as it seems to me (with some effort in the make_unique implementation), this can be resolved without this overspecification of the argument type.

Is this a resolvable defect in the `make_unique` implementation or is this an unresolvable, uninteresting edge-case no one should care about?

Comment: OK. let's delete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function template argument deduction does not work when being given a braced-init-list; it only works based on actual expressions.

It should also be noted that `positioned` cannot be list initialized from `{1, 2}` anyway. This will attempt to call a two argument constructor, and `positioned` has no such constructor. You would need to use `positioned({1, 2})` or `positioned{{1, 2}}`.

As such, the general solution would be to have `make_unique` somehow magically reproduce the signature of every possible constructor for the type it is constructing. This is obviously not a reasonable thing to do in C++ at this time.

An alternative would be to use a lambda to create the object, and write an alternative `make` function use C++17's guaranteed elision rules to apply the returned prvalue to the internal `new` expression:

```
template<typename T, typename Func, typename ...Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> inject_unique(Func f, Args &&...args)
{
  return std::unique_ptr<T>(new auto(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)));
}

auto ptr = inject_unique<positioned>([]() {return positioned({1, 2});});
```

You can even ditch the `typename T` parameter:

```
template<typename Func, typename ...Args>
auto inject_unique(Func f, Args &&...args)
{
  using out_type = decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
  return std::unique_ptr<out_type>(new auto(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)));
}

auto ptr = inject_unique([]() {return positioned({1, 2});});
```

Comment: Might be a dumb question but why aren't you using `make_unique`?

Comment: @Rakete1111: Because that would invoke a copy/move. Doing it this way, with guaranteed elision, does not. It constructs the object directly in place.

Comment: I just can't seem to get where the copy/move should happen. `make_unique` does exactly the same thing and also takes its parameters by (forwarding) reference, so I'm confused? Can you help me please :) Thanks

Comment: `make_unique` takes parameters. Those parameters are lvalues. Those parameters are then forwarded to the constructor of the object. That means those parameters will be copy/moved into the object from the parameter lvalues. So even if you pass a `positioned{{1, 2}}` prvalue to `make_unique`, it will copy/move from that parameter into the actual `positioned` object it creates. Using this functional style removes that possibility.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the most practical way to do this is probably to get rid of the braces, and add constructors to take the arguments discretely:

```
struct position
{
  int x, y;

  position(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};

class positioned
{
public:
  positioned(int x, int y) : pos(x, y) {}
private:
  position pos;
};

int main() { 
    auto bla = std::make_unique<positioned>(1,2);
}
```

If `position` had more than one ctor, you'd probably want to create a variadic template ctor for `positioned` to take some arbitrary parameters and pass them through to `position`'s ctor(s).

```
struct position
{
  int x, y;

  position(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
  position(int b) : x(b), y(b) {} // useless--only to demo a different ctor
};

class positioned
{
public:
  template <class... Args>
  positioned(Args&&... a) : pos(std::forward<Args>(a)...) {}
private:
  position pos;
};

int main() { 
    auto bla = std::make_unique<positioned>(1,2); // use 1st ctor
    auto bla2 = std::make_unique<positioned>(1); // use 2nd ctor
}
```

This way the arguments get forwarded through from `make_unique` to `positioned` to `position`. This does give at least some potential advantage in efficiency as well--instead of using the arguments to create a temporary object, which is then passed to initialize the underlying object, it passes (references to) the original objects directly to the ctor for the underlying object, so we only construct it once, in-place.

Note that this does give us a fair amount of versatility. For example, let's assume `positioned` were itself a template, and the underlying `position` a template argument:

```
#include <memory>

struct position2
{
  int x, y;

  position2(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};

struct position3 {
    int x, y, z;

    position3(int x, int y, int z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
};

template <class Pos>
class positioned
{
public:
  template <class... Args>
  positioned(Args&&... a) : pos(std::forward<Args>(a)...) {}
private:
  Pos pos;
};

int main() { 
    auto bla = std::make_unique<positioned<position2>>(1,2);
    auto bla2 = std::make_unique<positioned<position3>>(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Compatibility: I believe this requires C++ 14 or newer, since that's when `make_unique` got its forwarding/variadic ctor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that initalizers like `{1, 2}` cannot be deduced: the following code does not work (for good reason: what is the type of `{1, 2}` ?).

```
template<typename U>
void foo(U args) { }

foo({1, 2});
```

`make_unique` is just a more complex variation on this theme.

The root cause is explained in detail here: [initializer_list and template type deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431495/initializer-list-and-template-type-deduction)

Comment: I know what the problem is, I'm wondering if there's a way around it. (I hope) it should be possible in the cases I mention to force the braced init list to be matched to the constructor's argument types, making this asymmetry between calling new and make_unique go away.

Comment: well, the only way I see would be to make your own `make_unique` function that forwards to std::make_unique in the general case, and with specializations for types you want. (or you can play with ub and directly specialize std::make_unique...)

Comment: I thought specialising std things was permitted?

Comment: just checked and indeed specializing std::make_unique should be okay : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Adding_template_specializations ; it's only member functions that aren't