# C++ - Why does aggregate initialization not work with template struct

Tags: c++, templates, initialization, c++20, ctad

This code works, without having to specify a constructor:

```
struct Foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

//...

    int a1, b1;

    Foo foo = {a1, b1};
```

If I make Foo a template, it doesn't work.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct Foo
{
    T1 a;
    T2 b;
};

//...

    int a1, b1;

    Foo foo = {a1, b1};
```

It says deduction failed / 2 arguments were provided while 1 expected. If I add a constructor like `Foo(T1, T2){}` then it works. I thought, that sort of construction just works by default for structs. What am I getting wrong?

EDIT:
I'm using Clang, which seems not to support it. Both MSVC and GCC compile it with c++20 compiler flag.

Comment: It works when you explicitly specify `Foo<Int, int> foo = {a1, b1};`. https://godbolt.org/z/Eqcc7Pefn

Comment: Does this answer your question? [initializer\_list and template type deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431495/initializer-list-and-template-type-deduction)

Comment: This should make compilation possible `Foo foo = {{a1, b1}};`.

Comment: Your compiler probably doesn't implement the whole of C++20. An aggregate deduction guide should be synthesised.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since C++20 aggregates have implicitly-generated deduction guide so [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) works for aggregates too.

```
int a1, b1;
Foo foo = {a1, b1}; // works since C++20; T1 and T2 are deduced as int
```

Before C++20, you need to add user-defined deduction guide, e.g.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct Foo
{
    T1 a;
    T2 b;
};

template<class T1, class T2> Foo(T1 a, T2 b) -> Foo<T1, T2>;
```

---

As of Aug 2023, [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx20) has not supported *class template argument deduction for aggregates* yet, but the most recent Clang trunk [does support it](https://godbolt.org/z/vf4M6Pa3f) and, apparently, this will be supported in Clang 17.

Comment: I see. it works with GCC on godbolt, it doesn't work with Clang which is what I'm using.

Comment: @Newline Yes, [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx20) hasn't supported that. You cand add a user-defined deduction guide.

Comment: I've tweaked the final remark slightly - the feature was [commited](https://reviews.llvm.org/D139837) in December 2022, and will probably be in Clang 17.